# Memory Warning-MapOverlay

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview

I have question regarding memory usage of ios. I have implemented code as shown below and run it on the device about 10 min and it stopped and gave me warning "Received memory warning". I wonder why I am getting this warning.

```
NSArray *ants = [mapView overlays];
for(bb = 0; bb < [polygonArray count]; bb++){
        int attr=[[idArray objectAtIndex:bb]floatValue];


        coords = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb] count]);
        for (int a = 0;a < [[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb] count]; a++){
            coords[a].latitude = [[[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]objectAtIndex:a]objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
            coords[a].longitude = [[[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]objectAtIndex:a]objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
        }
        polygon = [[MKPolygon alloc]init];
        polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coords count:[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]count]]; 
        //free(coords);
        [previousPolygons addObject:polygon];

            }
        [mapView addOverlay:polygon];
        }

    }
[mapView removeOverlays:ants];
```

Comment: As a general tip your code will be much more readable if you assign `[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]` to a well named variable and use someting more descriptive that `bb` and `a`, but I guess you may have changed them just to obscure your code for public viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have more closing brackets that you have opening ones so there may be more at play than you've shown us, but I've shown what I think will improve your code below

```
NSArray *ants = [mapView overlays];
for(bb = 0; bb < [polygonArray count]; bb++){
    int attr=[[idArray objectAtIndex:bb]floatValue];


    coords = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb] count]);
    for (int a = 0;a < [[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb] count]; a++){
        coords[a].latitude = [[[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]objectAtIndex:a]objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
        coords[a].longitude = [[[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]objectAtIndex:a]objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
    }
    //Remove the next line because polygonWIthCoordinates creates one for you
    //polygon = [[MKPolygon alloc]init];
    polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coords count:[[polygonArray objectAtIndex:bb]count]]; 
    //reinstate this line
    free(coords);
    [previousPolygons addObject:polygon];

}
//This is outside the for-loop so you'll only be adding the last polygon
[mapView addOverlay:polygon];
}

}
[mapView removeOverlays:ants];
```